# Facebook page insights does not return for page_storytellers_by_country/days_28 and page_storytellers_by_age_gender/days_28

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Hi  um having a trouble of retrieving data for my page. These are the URL's um using to fetch data.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/140902935963424/insights/page_storytellers_by_country/days_28&access_token=[access_token]
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/140902935963424/insights/page_storytellers_by_age_gender/days_28&access_token=[access_token]
```

Um getting an empty result.

```
 "data": [
  {
     "id": "140902935963424/insights/page_storytellers_by_age_gender/days_28",
     "name": "page_storytellers_by_age_gender",
     "period": "days_28",
     "values": [
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2012-08-25T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2012-08-26T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2012-08-27T07:00:00+0000"
        }
     ],
     "title": "28 Days Demographics: People Talking About This",
     "description": "28 Days The number of People Talking About the Page by user age and gender (Unique Users)"
  }
```

],

but um getting impressions for other urls like

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/140902935963424/insights/page_impressions_by_city_unique/days_28&access_token=[access_token]
```

and um getting all the results. I want to know what has gone wrong. I found this like saying something about this. 
     https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/433795983308964/   He s talking about a threshhold limit which has undefined. Can any one help. Thank you.

Comment: It's likely that there are no records to report for the queried metrics.

Comment: for all insights use https://graph.facebook.com/140902935963424/insights?access_token=[access_token]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to achieve a lot of likes in order to have this sliced information, I'm testing about the threshold Matthew comment but it is really random, I have a page with 500 new daily likes with no sliced storyteller_by stats and another with over 4000 likes a week with this info available. I really think this isnt compromising likers privacy but what else...